# Hibernate Interceptor/Listeners for HQL

Tags: hibernate, listener

I have a spring web application where I want to block hibernate's insert/delete/update operation if the user in httpSession is a kind of Super user (where user.isSuper() returns true).

I have implemented listener for these events but the problem is that listener is not firing for HQL queries(session.executeUpdate()).

Same problem is with interceptors as well.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this following code instead of session.executeUpdate()  :-

```
  getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.NEVER);
  getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().close()
```